# How to use Raspberry Pi Clock Count for performance measurement

Tags: performance, arm, kernel, raspberry-pi2, cpu-registers

I make performance measurements on the Raspberry Pi and would like to have higher resolution then just clock_gettime().

Therefor I need to enable the CPU register PMUSERENR.

According to /proc/cpuinfo on my Raspberry Pi I have an "ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)". So I downloaded the architecture reference manual and found that I have to use:

CRn = c9, opc1 = 0, CRm = c14, opc2 = 0

```
asm ("MCR p15, 0, %0, C9, C14, 0\n\t" :: "r"(1));
```

But when using this code in a kernel module, I get following oops:

```
Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.604846] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] SMP ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.715199] Process insmod (pid: 2944, stack limit = 0xac80e210)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.722399] Stack: (0xac80fe90 to 0xac810000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.727920] fe80:                                     7f1ba0f8 00007fff 80098128 ac80fea8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.738472] fea0: 80578128 0000002d 00000000 7f1ba0f8 7f1ba0f8 7f1ba26c 7f1ba264 7f1ba134

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.749092] fec0: ac80e000 8057608c ac80feec ac80fed8 8057608c 00000000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.759724] fee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
pi@raspberrypi ~/projects/timer $ 
Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.770389] ff00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 76f5e948 00007390 00000000 76f7b390

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.781147] ff20: 76f5e948 b91a2390 ac80e000 00000000 ac80ffa4 ac80ff40 8009b6c4 80099714

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.792000] ff40: b919b000 00007390 b91a0598 b91a0457 b91a22c8 0000026c 000002ac 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.802930] ff60: 00000000 00000000 0000001f 00000020 0000000c 0000000a 00000009 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.813947] ff80: 7ea4371c 00000000 55afc028 00000080 8000fc28 ac80e000 00000000 ac80ffa8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.825056] ffa0: 8000fa20 8009b5f0 7ea4371c 00000000 76f74000 00007390 76f5e948 76f74000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.836170] ffc0: 7ea4371c 00000000 55afc028 00000080 55afbf78 00007390 76f5e948 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.847338] ffe0: 00000000 7ea436c4 76f55fb4 76ec0534 60000010 76f74000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Apr 29 20:58:12 ...
 kernel:[   84.880715] Code: e51b3084 e1530005 e2455008 0a000009 (e5953014)
```

I am new to kernel modules, so I do not know which direction I should go. Is there a good way to debug such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux kernel comes with a PMU driver. You could just leverage that. I would write a tutorial for you, but why reinvent the wheel when this guy explains it so well:
http://www.carbondesignsystems.com/virtual-prototype-blog/using-the-arm-performance-monitor-unit-pmu-linux-driver

Comment: Cool, I'll try that. But do you know what could cause my oops? Or where such an error could come from?

Comment: Seems like you have a crash in the insmod process and not the actual kernel module. If you remove the mcr statement and recompile the module, does insmod still crash? If yes, then the kernel headers you are using to compile the module are not compatible with the kernel you are actually running. Can you share the output of "uname -a" and your makefile?